# error in prepareForSegue as I try to create a variable set to sender as UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

My goal is to change the title of the next view to the text in the sender's cell.

This is my code:

```
        override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        // We check if we're navigating to the edit routine screen, and set
        // the delegate to this class.

        if segue.identifier == "editRoutine" {
        let navigationVC = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController
        let editRoutineVC = navigationVC.topViewController as EditRoutineViewController

        // App crashes in this next line..
        let cell = sender as UITableViewCell

        editRoutineVC.navigationItem.title = cell.textLabel?.text

        editRoutineVC.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: what error is generated...put that too

Comment: It's probably because your sender is not a UITableViewCell object.  show the line where you call 'performSegueWithIdentifier'

Comment: It's an optional for starters. So you should do :

`let cell: UITableViewCell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
    editRoutineVC.navigationItem.title = cell.textLabel?.text
} else {
    //assert some error
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a mixing of segues. I had one segue that led to the creation of a new cell object, and another that led to showing the details of said cell. I used the same code in prepareForSegue for both when I wanted different behavior on each view.